# mysql_result SHOWING SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: php

I am working with login system and having a error while using

**mysql_result()** function

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Here is the code

```
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `p32_users` WHERE `user_name` = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result(($query , 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 2 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This basicly means that it would take less than a minute for any visitor of your website to do whatever they want with your database. That includes destroying it. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Thank you . I m just doing it for localhost personal project and i will be on the way to POD :)

Comment: `return (` missing closing `)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses are messed up. It should be

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true: false;
```

Furthermore, there's no need for the ternary expression, since `==` returns `true` or `false` by itself. So just:

```
return mysql_result($query, 0) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should fix your problem:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
COUNT(user_id)
FROM p32_users
WHERE user_name='{$username}'
");

return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true: false;
```